# Discreate GPU (7670M) not being detected Ubuntu 14.04 , Hp laptop with dual graphics ( 7640G + 7670M)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg

I have HP laptop (2005ax) with AMD A8 processor and dual GPU 7640G + 7670M 
I'm running ubuntu 14.04 with AMD proprietary drivers installed.

**I'm not able to select discrete GPU, hence not being able to use full potential of my hardware on Ubuntu**

Not able to use discrete GPU 7670M in Ubuntu 14.04.

Machine info

```
dave@dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ uname -a 
Linux dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC 3.13.0-30-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:40:53 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 

dave@dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci | grep VGA 
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity [Radeon HD 7640G] 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] 

dave@dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ fglrxinfo 
display: :0  screen: 0 
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7640G 
OpenGL version string: 4.4.12967 Compatibility Profile Context 14.20
```

upon running aticonfig --initial i get this new xorg

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Card 0"
    BusID       "PCI:0@0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Default Card 1"
    BusID       "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSectionn
```

But this xorg.conf resets itself after restart

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 1"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection
```

I have tried these commands to select the GPU

```
sudo amdconfig --px-dgpu   # Activate discrete GPU (High-Performance mode), must re-start X to take effect
sudo amdconfig --px-igpu   # Activate integrated GPU (Power-Saving mode), must re-start X to take effect
```

But i unable to use my discrete GPU (7670M) has it is not activated

```
root@dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~# amdconfig --pxl 
PowerXpress: Discrete GPU is active (High-Performance mode).
root@dave-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~# fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7640G
OpenGL version string: 4.4.12967 Compatibility Profile Context 14.20
```

**Ubuntu 14.04 is not detecting 7670M  and only 7640G is working.
Anyone please help.**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same GPUs on ASUS and activating the integrated GPU works for me with the latest AMD beta driver 14.6:

```
K75DE:~$ sudo amdconfig --px-igpu
....
K75DE:~$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7640G
OpenGL version string: 4.4.12967 Compatibility Profile Context 14.20



display: :0  screen: 1
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series
OpenGL version string: 4.4.12967 Compatibility Profile Context 14.20
```

Still I can't do "anything" as it is low power mode, but separate tasks work well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and was able to find a helpful answer from ubuntu bug reports. It seems that `gpu-manager` is resetting your `xorg.conf` file.

You can stop that by commenting out the `start on` lines in the file `/etc/init/gpu-manager.conf`. This should help you solve the problem of the vanishing `xorg.conf` file.

Later you can do a `aticonfig --initial --adapter=1` with additional parameters to setup your `xorg.conf` with the dedicated GPU

The bug report is here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1310489